# I get different numbers in excel on different PCs using EPPlus generated file

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have this code in my C# application to generate Excel files using EPPlus, everything works nicely, i send the application to client and he says that it shows wrong numbers. In the Excel files he sent me back, the numbers are really different. Can't figure out why. I suspect Excel is the culprit, interpreting numbers differently because of region settings or something similar. How can i fix this?
For example, 20 becomes 2000 on another PC:

```
Decimal.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[15].Value.ToString().Replace(".", ","), out number); //cell value 20.00
ws.Cells["I33"].Value = number;
ws.Cells["I33"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;
ws.Cells["I33"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00"; //becomes 20,00
```

Results:
[image: results]

Comment: Replace commas that should be decimal points with decimal points. That should prevent localisation confusion. Really, you should only use commas for thousands seperation. a decimal point is called that for a reason

Comment: I think i tried that and it didn't work. On my pc, in region settings->numbers comma is set as the decimal symbol. Maybe on his pc, it's a dot. Ok, i'll try two things, replace comma with a dot, or store numbers in excel as text, and see if excel can convert them back to numbers in formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is small example:

```
string decimalStr1 = "123,34";
string decimalStr2 = "123.34";

decimal number1, number2 = 0m;

decimal.TryParse(decimalStr1.Replace(",", "."), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number1);
decimal.TryParse(decimalStr2.Replace(",", "."), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number2);

// number1 = number2 = 123.34
```

Important is to use '.' as a separator and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Ant then after parse (you are sure that value is correct) you can change separator back to ',':

```
ws.Cells["I33"].Value = number1.ToString().Replace('.', ',');
```

Comment: Ha, i tried your suggestion and got the number 2000 on my PC, well thats progress, now i know how to get both numbers and can continue finding the solution.
By the way, it should be: Decimal.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[15].Value.ToString().Replace(".", ","), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out skaicius);

Comment: I like your idea to convert to comma before inserting value into excel, i'l try that.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think you should use a Repla‌​ce(",", ".") in TryParse method to be sure shat a decimal point is '.'- default decimal point in the InveriantCulture

Comment: I checked that dots were used everywhere in the numbers that i worked with, so i got local decimal separator like this `string separator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;`
And used it in the last insert into excel `ws.Cells["I33"].Value = number1.ToString().Replace('.', separator);`
Though i needed to insert number into excel, because it is used in the formula, but number stored as text also works. So i hope this will solve it. I'm waiting for clients answer. You helped me understand C# Cultures in general, so i'll mark your answer as correct. Thank you.